# How to get saved elementor template list programmatically?

Tags: plugins

I want to get the saved elementor template list (from this location wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=elementor_library&tabs_group=library) programmatically and display its name as dropdown select menu. How to do that?

Comment: You'll need to inquire in Elementor's support channels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my own answer.

To get the elementor template list you can use this snippets code

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'elementor_library',
  'posts_per_page' => 30,
  'tabs_group' => 'library',
  'elementor_library_type' => 'page',
);

$elementor_templates = get_posts($args);
```

Now, to display it as dropdown select element, you can iterate through `elementor_templates`

```
foreach ($elementor_templates as $elementor_template) {
  echo $elementor_template->post_title;
}
```